# Print Next Line When Error Occurs

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using exception I need to print the next value after an error occurred.
For example

```
FOR i IN 1..50
IF MOD(i,5) <> 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line(i);
```

I need to print all values except values divisible by 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what error do you need to handle? The snippet of code you posted won't throw an error and it's not clear what the wider program does. So this question is unanswerable without further clarification.

Comment: I need to raise an error

Comment: What error do need to raise? We cannot help if you won't explain your question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If this would be code in pl/sql then you are very close - just try to add: `BEGIN`, `LOOP`, `END IF`, `END LOOP` and `END` clauses:

```
begin
  FOR i IN 1..50 LOOP
    IF MOD(i,5) <> 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

---

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
16
17
18
19
21
22
23
24
26
27
28
29
31
32
33
34
36
37
38
39
41
42
43
44
46
47
48
49
```

Comment: I need to use an exception along with this